# React Navigation StackNavigator doesn't work within SwitchNavigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am using React Navigation to implement authentication. I want that if there is a valid token the user will be directed to app navigator. Otherwise, he will be directed to auth navigator.

In my implementation the loading screen mounts, also the auth, but I see nothing.

index.js :

```js
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import app from './app';
import auth from './auth';
import loading from './loading-screen'

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        loading,
        app,
        auth
    }
));
```

loading-screen.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  AsyncStorage,
  StatusBar,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

export default class LoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getUser();
  }

  getUser = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');

    this.props.navigation.navigate(token ? 'app' : 'auth');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

app.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const login = () => (
    <View>
        <Text>login</Text>
    </View>
);

export default createStackNavigator({login});
```

If I am exporting the login component from auth.js without `createStackNavigator` function, it works and I see login on the screen. With it, it doesn't.

Comment: Where do you see 2? I only have one in index.js

Comment: sorry I thought there was two, and your components should all starts with a capital letter.

Comment: and your code seems to work https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/delete-me3

Comment: didn't worked. I don't know how it works on Snack